# OpenCSV parser unable to parse double quotes in the data

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have following CSV file,

```
"id","Description","vale"
1,New"Account","val1"
```

I am unable to read the above CSV file with OpenCSV. It cannot read `New"Account`, since the double quotes inside data. My CSV reader constructor is:

```java
csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(currentFile), ',', '\"', '\0');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is as designed. Your constructor specifies a quote character as `"\""` so `OpenCSV` will treat that character as a quote character, i.e. when it reads a quote it will ignore all commas until a matching quote is found.

To get around this you could use a `FilterReader`.

```
    Reader reader = new FilterReader(fileReader) {

        private int filter(int ch) {
            return ch == '"'?' ':ch;
        }
        @Override
        public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            int red = super.read(cbuf, off, len);
            for ( int i = off; i < off + red; i++) {
                cbuf[i] = (char)filter(cbuf[i]);
            }
            return red;
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return filter(super.read());
        }

    };
```

Comment: is there any way to read the data with quotes? something like replacing quotes with space ?

Comment: @Chinnu - Yes - wrap your `Reader` in a [FilterReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterReader.html).

Comment: Thanks OldCurmudgen, I want to replace the quotes only inside data, not leading and trailing quotes. Could you please modify the code for that?

Comment: @Chinnu - The code is a demo of how to make a filter. I am sure you can work on it to achieve what you want. Something like only removing `"` when not before or after a `,` but there are still edge cases such as end-of-line.

Comment: Thanks OldCurmudgen....sure i will try like you mentioned...is there any performance issue , if large csv files comes in?  since we are processing each character.

Answer (score 3):

This is invalid csv:

`1,New"Account","val1"`

should be:

`1,"New""Account","val1"` -> if you want `1  New"Account  val1`

or

`1,"New""Account""","val1"` -> if you want `1  New"Account"  val1`

Quotes inside (quoted) fields, must be escaped with another quote.

While you could change your code to read the malformed csv correctly, the csv data should be fixed in the first place, because you might get some more erros with larger csv-files or updates of that data.

Usually, quotes are used when there is a seperator or another quote inside the field. So if you would ignore the quotes and only split on the seperator, there will be problems if there is a seperator inside a field in future updates of the data - for example:

```
1,"John, Doe",123
```